# Promblem with <form> tag in HTML

Tags: html, web-deployment, web-deployment-project, htmlelements, html-formhandler

I have face this problem  tag. Every time i click enter after filled any one of the text area in the form, it redirect me to my email. Why?? I want clear one thing that I'm totally a beginner.

```
<form action="mailto:priyaksheem96@gmail.com" Method="post" Enctype="text/plain">
```

[image]

Ps: I'm using "Atom"

Comment: Just a note: it's considered good practice to keep all HTML elements and attributes lowercase.

Comment: You're using a mailto action on your form (`action="mailto:someone@domain.com"`). On submit, the form values are passed to the user's local email client.

Answer (score 1):

Mailto link is a type of HTML link that activates the default mail client on the computer for sending an e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Let's answer your questions one by one:

### 1- Why does your form automatically submit when you hit enter?

The `action` property of your form is the URL to which your form will be submitted. And by default, when you hit enter in a form, the form will automatically submit.

### 2- Why does it open your email app on form submit?

Well, your form's `action` is set to `mailto:priyaksheem96@gmail.com`, and `mailto:` URIs always redirect to your default mail app.

If you want your web application to send an email automatically instead, you will need some server-side work. Implement a backend script (PHP, C#, whatever), and modify your form's action so that it submits to that script instead of `mailto:`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by *it redirect me to my email* you mean that it opens your email client, that is the expected behaviour. A `mailto` link opens your email client and writes the email address into the `To` field, as well as a subject and message if specified.

As this doesn't seem to be the behaviour that you are expecting, I'm assuming that you want the form to actually send an email to that email address. You'll need to do this differently.

In the `action` attribute, put the name of a `.php` file. In this PHP file, access the form data using `$_POST`, and send an email using the `mail()` function.